# Replce utf to unicode using xslt with help of database.xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to replace all utf to unicode as below given example using xslt.

Here many utf entities are in my xml and just want to replace then to unicode using xslt with help of a database file which contains all utf and unicode values as well.

Please refer to below given example.

database.xml:-

```
<entities>
<entity utf8="Â°" unicode="x00B0" iso="deg" latin1="176"/>
<entity utf8="Ã­" unicode="x00ED" iso="iacute" latin1="237"/>
<entity utf8="Ã©" unicode="x00E9" iso="eacute" latin1="233"/>
<entity utf8="Ã³" unicode="x00F3" iso="oacute" latin1="243"/>
<entity utf8="â¢" unicode="x2062" iso="InvisibleTimes" latin1="Not Available"/>
</entities>
```

input:-

```
<article>
<documentinfo>
<title lang="eng">First report on the contribution of small-sized species to the copepod community structure of the southern Patagonian shelf (Argentina, 47-55Â°S)</title>
<author>
<lastname>Julieta</lastname>
<firstname>Carolina</firstname>
<middlename>Antacli</middlename>
<fullname>Carolina Antacli Julieta</fullname>
<corresponding>yes</corresponding>
<email>James@gmail.com</email>
<affiliation>Consejo Nacional de Investigaciones CientÃ­ficas y TÃ©cnicas (CONICET). Av. Rivadavia 1917, C1033AAJ, Buenos Aires, Argentina,</affiliation>
<affiliation>Instituto Nacional de InvestigaciÃ³n y Desarrollo Pesquero (INIDEP). Paseo Victoria Ocampo 1, B7602HSA, Mar del Plata, Argentina</affiliation>
<affiliation>Instituto de Investigaciones Marinas y Costeras (IIMYC), CONICET-Universidad Nacional de Mar del Plata, Argentina</affiliation>
</author>
```

Output:-

```
<article>
<documentinfo>
<title lang="eng">First report on the contribution of small-sized species to the copepod community structure of the southern Patagonian shelf (Argentina, 47-55&#x00B0;S)</title>
<author>
<lastname>Julieta</lastname>
<firstname>Carolina</firstname>
<middlename>Antacli</middlename>
<fullname>Carolina Antacli Julieta</fullname>
<corresponding>yes</corresponding>
<email>James@gmail.com</email>
<affiliation>Consejo Nacional de Investigaciones Cient&#x00ED;ficas y T&#x00E9;cnicas (CONICET). Av. Rivadavia 1917, C1033AAJ, Buenos Aires, Argentina,</affiliation>
<affiliation>Instituto Nacional de Investigaci&#x00F3;n y Desarrollo Pesquero (INIDEP). Paseo Victoria Ocampo 1, B7602HSA, Mar del Plata, Argentina</affiliation>
<affiliation>Instituto de Investigaciones Marinas y Costeras (IIMYC), CONICET-Universidad Nacional de Mar del Plata, Argentina</affiliation>
</author>
</documentinfo>
</article>
```

You can download all files from:- http://www.stylusstudio.com/SSDN/upload/Entities-Replacement.zip also.

Comment: i have tried <character-map> but didn't get any thing.
working on XSLT 2.0

Comment: Then, why not show us the code you've come up with so far instead of letting us do it from scratch and guess where you went wrong?

Comment: If the output is supposed to be UTF-8, why does it have character references like `&#x00F3;` and not simply the characters like `ó`?

Comment: Sorry! Now i have update all the xml

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360735/replace-a-string-with-a-string-with-xslt by Dimitre Novatchev. I have tested it using your inputs but I am getting `&amp;#x00B0;`, etc.

Comment: Can you share me your code.

Comment: As formulated, the question is incomprehensible; readers can only guess at what you mean.  'UTF' is not in itself a standard term; you might mean UTF-8 or UTF-16 or any of a number of Unicode encoding formats.  And what you mean by 'utf entity' only you can possibly know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the encoding of a file, you better use a tool like iconv. E.g.

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UCS-2LE input_UTF8.xml > output_UCS.xml
```

This info on internationalization and encoding might be useful as well; http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch08_06.htm

That said, character-map does work with the input.xml you've uploaded;

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:character-map name="specialsigns">
        <xsl:output-character character="°" string="x00B0"/>
        <xsl:output-character character="í" string="x00ED"/>
        <xsl:output-character character="é" string="x00E9"/>
        <xsl:output-character character="ó" string="x00F3"/>
    </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" use-character-maps="specialsigns"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a modified stylesheet from [replace a string with a string with xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360735/replace-a-string-with-a-string-with-xslt).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('entities.xml')/entities/*"/>

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($vReps/@utf8[contains($pText, .)])">
                <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pReps"
                        select="$vReps[contains($pText, @utf8)]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="multiReplace">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>
        <xsl:param name="pReps"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pReps">
                <xsl:variable name="escaped">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#', $pReps[1]/@unicode, ';')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="vRepResult">
                    <xsl:call-template name="singleReplace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pOld" select="$pReps[1]/@utf8"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pNew" select="$escaped"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$vRepResult"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pReps" select="$pReps[position() >1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="singleReplace">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>
        <xsl:param name="pOld"/>
        <xsl:param name="pNew"/>

        <xsl:if test="$pText">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $pOld))">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $pOld)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$pNew" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="singleReplace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $pOld)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pOld" select="$pOld"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pNew" select="$pNew"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your inputs, I get:

```
<article>
    <documentinfo>
        <title lang="eng">First report on the contribution of small-sized species to the copepod community structure of the southern Patagonian shelf (Argentina, 47-55&amp;#x00B0;S)</title>
        <author>
            <lastname>Julieta</lastname>
            <firstname>Carolina</firstname>
            <middlename>Antacli</middlename>
            <fullname>Carolina Antacli Julieta</fullname>
            <corresponding>yes</corresponding>
            <email>James@gmail.com</email>
            <affiliation>Consejo Nacional de Investigaciones Cient&amp;#x00ED;ficas y T&amp;#x00E9;cnicas (CONICET). Av. Rivadavia 1917, C1033AAJ, Buenos Aires, Argentina,</affiliation>
            <affiliation>Instituto Nacional de Investigaci&amp;#x00F3;n y Desarrollo Pesquero (INIDEP). Paseo Victoria Ocampo 1, B7602HSA, Mar del Plata, Argentina</affiliation>
            <affiliation>Instituto de Investigaciones Marinas y Costeras (IIMYC), CONICET-Universidad Nacional de Mar del Plata, Argentina</affiliation>
        </author>
    </documentinfo>
</article>
```

All credit goes to Dimitre Novatchev.